# swift performSegueWithIdentifier sender value

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to understand how the sender value works in segues.

In some places in my code both works:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: self)

performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: sender)
```

But what is the difference between having self / sender?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @iosDev82 says in his answer, sender is an optional that names the object (if any) that triggered the segue.

If you trigger a segue through code in a view controller, you could pass the view controller (self), or you could pass nil. It's just a piece of information that is passed along to prepareForSegue (again as iOSDv82 says.)

If you trigger a segue in the code of an IBAction method, your IBAction may have it's own sender parameter (frequently a button.) In that case you can pass along the sender parameter to the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.

Example:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton)
{
  //In this case the button IBAction takes a pointer to the button as a param.
  //Pass it on to the segue in case performWithSegue needs it. 
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someID", sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: But this is also a button and it works, what is the difference:
@IBAction func Mybutton(sender: AnyObject) { selfperformSegueWithIdentifier("someID", sender: self) }

I am trying to look it up in the docs, can't find it : /

Comment: The sender parameter is whatever you want it to be. If you need to know which button the user pressed to trigger the segue, pass the button (sender) along to `performSegueWithIdentifier`. If you need to know the view controller, pass that. If you don't care, pass nil. The info is for you, and will be passed to your `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: Furthermore, you *could* even pass, say, a dictionary with keys and values that you need to set on the destination view controller...

Comment: Thanks, but is it kinda like a replacement for prepareForSegue ? I mean the way I can choose what to pass along

Comment: @nhgrif Thanks, but is it kinda like a replacement for prepareForSegue ? I mean the way I can choose what to pass along

Comment: Argggggh! No, we are talking about the sender parameter, who's purpose is to be passed along to your `prepareForSegue` method. It is in no way a *replacement* for `prepareForSegue`. It's a piece of information that gets *passed* to `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: @DuncanC thanks for finally making it clear to me, was an aha moment. Haha sorry! english is not my first languish

Answer (score 2):

`sender` is just an argument that gets passed along with this function.

This is received later in the function `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)`, where you can get this object and make decision based on who the sender is.

Answer (score 0):

As an Example, suppose you want to edit something at an **IndexPath**. You call

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "showItem", sender: indexPath)`

from wherever you want (*indexPath* is of type **IndexPath** here).

Then, inside the `prepare(segue:sender:)`, you do:

```
...
switch segue.identifier {
case "showItem"?:
     // Figure out which row was just tapped
     if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
         editRow(segue, row)
     } else {
         let selectedIndexPath = sender as! IndexPath
         editRow(segue, selectedIndexPath.row)
     }
...
```